# Youtube Send Private Message via Post

Tags: c#, vb.net, http, post, youtube

I'm trying to make a Post Method in the private message of Youtube.

Heres the URL
"All urls have removed dots and http:// to prevent this question to be blocked as a spam"

```
www_youtube_com/inbox?feature=mhee&folder=messages
```

In C# I Already made the "login" post method, here's the snippet:

```vb
Dim url As String = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=true&hl=pt_BR&service=youtube&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26hl%3Dpt_BR%26next%3D%252F%26nomobiletemp%3D1&uilel=3"
Dim formUrl As String = url
Dim formParams As String = String.Format("Email={0}&Passwd={1}", "*********", "**********")
Dim cookieheader As String

Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(formUrl)
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.Method = "POST"
Dim bytes() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams)
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length
Using os As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
End Using
Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
cookieheader = resp.Headers("Set-cookie")
cookies.SetCookies(resp.ResponseUri, resp.Headers("Set-cookie"))
resp.Close()

'starts sending msg
Dim httpreq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.youtube.com/inbox_ajax")
httpreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpreq.Method = "POST"
formParams = String.Format("action_ajax=1&type=send_message&message_text={2}&subject={1}&to_users={0}&video_id={3}", "user", "subject", "message_body", "videoid")
bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams)
httpreq.ContentLength = bytes.Length
httpreq.CookieContainer = cookies
httpreq.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieheader)
Using os As Stream = httpreq.GetRequestStream()
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
End Using
resp = httpreq.GetResponse()
```

The user, subject, message_body, and videoid fields were filled with real data to be correctly tested...

I Already tried to change sometimes the HTTPREQ URL, so it could match the youtube form website, but, using firebug, i catch those informations:

URL that the post occur when I do it manually in the Firefox using Firebug:

```
www_youtube_com/inbox_ajax?action_ajax=1&type=send_message
```

```
Message Parameters:
[{"type":"send_message","request":{"message_text":"Test6","subject":"Test5","to_users":"HTDANILO","video_id":"ph0TNYQllRQ"}}]
```

The firebug also says that the Referer site is:

```
www_youtube_com/inbox?feature=mhee&folder=messages
```

But I already tried to do the post in there, also tried in http://www.youtube.com/inbox, neither worked.

Someone could point me so i can understand why it isnt working?

Sorry for bad English, not my native language and thanks in advice!

Comment: Are you making a malicious bot?

Comment: Well, this sounds fishy.

Comment: Its just a test, im going to make a giveaway in my channel to people who comment, i need it to get all comments, randomize like, 100, and send them the "cd key" so they can redeem a game... if it does not send the msg with a program, ofc there will be a delay that will not be good

Comment: No one can help? Of I'll not make a malicious bot... every question regarding POST methods and HTML would be a malicious bot?

Comment: Youtube has a comprehensive API which limits spam and other bot like behavior for a reason.

Comment: Yeah, Already gave up, thinking in another way to giveaway the keys